# "Special Price" is not translated

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I am using the latest Magento DE version (1.9.0.1) and while everything else works fine (like "Regular price") "Special price" is not translated. I've tried changing the "Mage_Catalog.csv" in the "locale/de_DE" folder and it is there. I noticed, that other than said in the translation file there is no column behind "Special price", so I changed the file to:

```
"Special Price:","Sonderpreis:"
"Special Price","Sonderpreis:"
"Special Price: %s","Sonderpreis: %s"
"Special Price %s","Sonderpreis: %s"
```

(just for testing purposes of course) and it still won't change. As far as I can tell the text is called in the price.phtml file as "Special price". 
 What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The definitive answer to this question is that **Special Price** is an `attribute`.

You can simply translate the Special Price `price-label` from your Magento Admin Panel, just go to

```
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
```

and open the Special Price attribute (attribute code `special_price`).

From there select the tab `Manage Label / Options`.

Here you can set the proper translation for each of your store views.

[image]

After saving the attribute don't forget to flush Magento cache.

Comment: Just saved me hours of find filing and going through templates. OFCOURSE!

Comment: Yup Thank you SIR in 1.9 this is 100% the case for how to update that text.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you use the exact string for the first quotes. In this case you see this code in the price.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?>
```

i.e. you need **Special Price:** for the first quotes in your translate file. So your first try

```
"Special Price:","Sonderpreis:"
```

should've worked. In some cases this translation doesn't work. Than you have to force this translation with

```
"Mage_Catalog::Special Price:","Sonderpreis:"
```

This goes in your translate file at

> app/design/frontend/default/yourdesign/locale/de_DE/translate.csv

Hope this helps!

**+++ EDIT after Comment +++**

There are 22 occurrences of this 'Special Price:'

[image: 22 occurrences]

Comment: Sadly it didn't:
I did just as you said, but it didn't work.
So I checked everything again and found something strange:
In the file "app/design/frontend/myPackage/default/template/catalog/product" (as well es at default/default) it says "<span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?></span>". It is the only occurence of "Special Price". On the frontend however there is no column after it.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after your changes? -
See my update for your other Question!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to translate it at a module/extension level. Because the pricing is handled via price.phtml inside your theme folder, you should be using a theme level translation for price related language translation via:

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
```

Comment: This is actually the path that I have tried already since it is basically a general mistake and I want to solve it for every Theme.

Comment: You could turn on inline translation and try that.

Comment: Works for everything besides both of the price names ;) The "Edit" icon appears, but nothing happens if I click it. Works perfectly everywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Within price.phtml you'll find in Version 1.9 the following line

```
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
```

You have to translate the attribute in the Magento backend

```
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
```

So this is definitive the answer :-) After a lot of grep, i finally found it.